# Loading online google maps in AutoCAD?

Tags: google-maps, autocad

How do I load Google imagery (online Google Maps) into AutoCAD Map 3D 2010 ?

Answer (score 1):

With AutoCAD Civil 3D you can get the Spatial Manager™ App.

This supports adding in background mapping from various sources.

Help guide:

https://apps.autodesk.com/CIV3D/en/Detail/HelpDoc?appId=5328176051015692431&appLang=en&os=Win32_64#inunininfo

Link to App Store:

https://apps.autodesk.com/CIV3D/en/Detail/Index?id=5328176051015692431&appLang=en&os=Win32_64

Answer (score 0):

You can find more about it in the following blog entries, Hope this helps

http://www.spatialmanager.com/google-maps-in-your-cad-drawings-of-course/
http://www.spatialmanager.com/more-about-dynamic-google-maps-in-your-drawings-or-maps/

Answer (score -1):

Spatial Manager for AutoCAD. See http://www.spatialmanager.com/spm-forautocad/

Comment: Thanks for the input, Sergio, but please don't post answers consisting of only a link. Rather include relevant information (e.g. code or relevant features of tools) in your answer and use the link only as additional information.